# Process files then modify filenames

Tags: python

I am processing files in a directory and after processing a file I want to save it using the original name but also add xx to the file name.  My purpose is to identify which files have been processed.

Basic suggestions as to how to proceed are appreciated

Comment: Welcome to SO! What exactly have you tried so far? We're much more here to help with specific questions of the form "I tried X, but it did not do what I expect and instead resulted in an error!" accompanied by a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Consider looking at the `glob` package for getting a list of filenames.  For changing filenames, simply use string concatenation:  `new_name = filename + ".xx"`

Answer (score 1):

If the only purpose is flag the file in order to know which files have been processed I would try another strategy (adding file metadata or something). But from your question, I infer the only thing you need is a rename of the file after being processed... You can use `os.rename`:

```py
import os

filename = "example.txt"
flag_suffix = ".xx"


with open(filename, "wb+") as f:
    # process file
    ...

os.rename(filename, f"{filename}{flag_suffix}")
```